# Copy variables in FitNesse

Tags: fitnesse, fitnesse-slim

1)
!| Script                     |com.playtech.openapi.core.fitnesse.tests.Fixtures   |
|$response=|createGroup |121312441||MyGroup|
|$id=|getParameterFromResponse    |$response|

!define groupId $id

2)
!| Script                     |com.playtech.openapi.core.fitnesse.tests.Fixtures   |
|$response=|createMember|Alex|
|$id=|getParameterFromResponse |$response|

!define memberId $id

3)
!| Script                     |com.playtech.openapi.core.fitnesse.tests.Fixtures   |
|addMemberToGroup|${memberId}||${groupId}|

How can I copy value from $id to groupId? Because my example doesn't work

PS: results of getParameterFromResponse  should be necessarily defined as $id parameter in step 1 and 2. And  memberId doesn't equal groupId

Answer (score 0):

You're using two separate concepts as if they were the same.

`!define` uses markup variables which are part of the FitNesse wiki markup and are used for macro-replacement in pages. They provide another way to parameterize your tests with static values (**not changing during a test execution**).  See http://fitnesse.org/FitNesse.UserGuide.FixtureGallery.ImportantConcepts.MarkupVariables

The symbols in the Slim tables are dynamically assigned values during test execution.  See http://www.fitnesse.org/FitNesse.UserGuide.WritingAcceptanceTests.SliM.SymbolsInTables

The two concepts can not be interleaved because the first is assigned statically by the Wiki engine and the second is assigned dynamically by the Slim test engine.

Comment: So how can I assign value of $id to another variable? Could you show me please an example?

Comment: Sorry, I haven't used the Slim test system so I don't know how to do that - all my work is with the Fit test system